# Java - Can objects store its interface type?

Tags: java, interface

I know you if you make an new interface type, you can store objects that have implemented that interface since they are the same type.

However, does it work the other way around? Say you create a new class object x, can you store in it the interface in which the object implemented?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean exactly by "store it in the interface"

Comment: I mean make a new object with the subclass and set it = to the interface

Comment: Do you mean having a reference of type `SomeInterface` and assign it to a variable of type `SomeClass implements SomeInterface`? If that's the case, the answer is **no**. I strongly recommend you to add a code example to your description.

Comment: This should make it clear: • Create objects from two classes that implement an interface. Store 
them in variables named a and b, of the appropriate class type. Create a variable whose type is the interface type. Call it i. Can we store a or b into i? (Yes). Can we store i into a or b? (This is my question)

Comment: You can't create a variable of an interface type.  You can only create variables of class types, maybe an anonymous class but still a class type.

Comment: Well, you can create a variable of a type given by some interface, what you cannot do is instantiate an object which is solely instance of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick and simple answer. You cannot cast your parent class into the child class.

In other words:

```
ParentClass parent = new ChildClass(); // VALID
ChildClass child = new ParentClass(); // INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

[Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5232319/joel-min) already answered the main question, but just for the sake of completeness, given:

```
interface Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal {}

class Cat implements Animal {}
```

#### And given the following variables:

```
Animal animal1 = new Dog();
Animal animal2 = new Cat();
Cat    cat     = new Cat();
Dog    dog     = new Dog();
```

#### The following are **valid**:

```
   animal1 = animal2; // since all animals are animals
   animal1 = cat;     // since all cats are animals
   animal2 = cat;     // since all cats are animals
   animal1 = dog;     // since all dogs are animals
   animal2 = dog;     // since all dogs are animals
```

#### But this ones are **invalid**:

```
  cat = animal1;
```

Because we only know about the object referenced by `animal1` that it is an Animal, but we cannot assure that it will be a Cat.

```
  dog = animal1;
```

The same happens here, we already saw an example were `animal1` could get a cat assigned. In other words, this is not valid because not all animals are dogs.